# Change Emacs home directory for all purposes

Tags: directories

I have my config files in `~/config/emacs` which `~/.emacs` is symlinked to.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the default "emacs root directory" `$HOME` in all contexts (unless overridden by a buffer-local variable), whether launching an ansi terminal, launching dired, or anything like that.

```
$ ls -al .emacs.d | perl -pe 's/^.*([.]emacs[.]d)/$1/'
.emacs.d -> ./config/emacs
```

My `.emacs.d/init.el` file contains the following snippet in an attempt to force emacs open stuff like `dired` and `ansi-term` in my home directory.

```
(cd (getenv "HOME"))
```

How do I change the effective root directory for `ansi-term` and everything else?

Here's a complete example that should reproduce the surprising behavior I'm talking about on OS X and Linux.

I have a directory `~/tmp/emacs`

```
$ echo '(cd (getenv "HOME"))' > ~/tmp/emacs/cd.el
$ cd /tmp
$ emacs -q -l ~/tmp/emacs/cd.el
```

And then from inside `emacs`,

Launch the ansi terminal and accept the default shell

```
M-x ansi-term C-m C-m
```

print the current working directory from inside the terminal

```
$ pwd
/tmp
```

I expected working directory to be `$HOME`.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a scalpel instead of a sledge hammer -- i.e., How do I launch Emacs and open a dired-mode buffer in a specific directory from the terminal?  How do I launch Emacs and open an ansi-term buffer in a specific directory from the terminal?  Etc.  All of this can be achieved without altering system-wide or Emacs-session-wide defaults.  I find individual solutions to be better than global solutions, that will undoubtedly have corner-cases and cause some problems in the future (some of which will be difficult to trace).

Comment: @lawlist I think the sledgehammer is what I'm after. I just want emacs to behave as if it was started somewhere else. The default behavior is great when the path to my `.emacs.d/init.el` file doesn't contain symlinks. I was actually kind of surprised that emacs considered `~/.emacs.d/..` to be its root/home directory rather than just `~`.

Comment: Once Emacs is open you can set an environmental variable with `setenv` -- e.g., `(setenv "HOME" "/private/tmp")`.  I don't know if that helps any, but I just tried it in an `eshell` buffer and was able to `cd` to the new HOME directory by typing `cd ~` after using `setenv`.  You can probably do that while launching Emacs -- there are ways to pass `elisp` while launching Emacs from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easy if you consider that `default-directory` (the variable returned by `pwd`) is always buffer local and returns the default directory of the current buffer.

With the following addition, you can watch, what's going on:

```el
(cd (getenv "HOME"))
(message "Current dir: %s" (pwd))
(message "Current buffer: %s" (buffer-name))
```

Without any file loaded, the file will be executed in the context of the first buffer created and that's `*scratch*`. After the initialization (and the file loaded with `-l` belongs to this phase) a new buffer with the start message is created and this one doesn't get the `default-directory` from the `*scratch*` buffer.

**tl;dr** `default-directory` is per file and changes, when you call `ansi-term` (or `pwd`) with another buffer open. `cd` only changes the `default-directory` of the current buffer.